# Creating widget - ask for selecting a post in the admin panel

Tags: posts, customization, widgets, admin

First of all, sorry for my English, I'll try to make it understandable.
I'm new on WordPress; I already have created a few plugins but they didn't needed admin configuration.
Now I'd like to make an other one that creates a widget where the administrator can choose a post of a custom post type from a dropdown. I have a custom post type "event type 1" and another "event type 2", and I am trying to create a dropdown that lists posts of both of these post types.

I thought to make a request to list all post in a dropdown and then save the ID of this post. But I'm not sure it's the good way to do it, and I'm not even sure how I can do it in Wordpress.

If anybody has any tips on this, I would appreciate that.

For now this is a simple widget from a tutorial. I will change the display to have the information of the post I want and I have to add the dropdown for choosing the post. The current code is as follows:

```
// Creating the widget 
class event_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            // Base ID of your widget
            'event_widget', 

            // Widget name will event_widgetappear in UI
            __('Event Widget', 'my_event_widget'), 

            // Widget description
            array( 'description' => __( 'Event Widget', 'my_event_widget' ), )
        );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

        echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'my_event_widget' );
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }


    public function form( $instance ) {    
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'my_event_widget' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">
                <?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?>
            </label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name(     'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php 

    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }

}

function wpb_load_event_widget() {
    register_widget( 'event_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_event_widget' );
```

Comment: Have you already created a settings screen for your widget and are you just looking for a way to list posts of a custom post type in a dropdown?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm looking for

Comment: Please answer my question. Have you already created a settings screen for your widget?

Comment: Sorry, Yes i have already done it, i have all my code i just don't know how to display the list of custom post in the dropdown

Comment: Two more questions: Could you post your code in your original question? Do you want to display a dropdown with posts from both custom post types?

Comment: Yes i want a single dropdown for both custom types, i'll only make it twice, one for each language on the site, i'll use polylang option to choose only the ones i want in each dropdown

Answer (score 0):

First off, try to work on your code formatting. As it is, it's rather unreadable and this makes it not only more difficult for us to understand how to help you, but also less scalable and suited for future use. Always try to adhere to the [WordPress PHP Coding](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/) Standards.

Now, on to the beef of the problem...

To add a new setting to a widget, you have to implement functionality in two class method of the class you already have: `form()` and `update()`. In `form()`, we're going to display the post dropdown, and in `update()`, we're going to save the selected post.

#### Displaying the dropdown

To display the dropdown, we utilize [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), which creates a query for fetching all posts. We place this code in the `form` function before actually displaying anything. The code below fetches *all* (`posts_per_page=1`) posts from post types *post and page* (`post_type=post,page`), ordering them by title (`orderby=post_title`) ascendingly (`order=ASC`). The resulting posts are stored in the property `$posts_query->posts`.

```
$posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ), // Replace by your posts types for event type 1 and 2
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
) );
```

Next, we display the dropdown in the `form()` method as well, by simply looping over the posts found.

```
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Post' ); ?></label>
    <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post' ); ?>" class="widefat">
        <?php foreach ( $posts_query->posts as $post ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" <?php selected( $post->ID, $instance['post'] ); ?>>
                <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Try to understand the code above, as you will need it for creating more widget options in the future!

#### Saving the post selected in the form

Now, we use the `update()` method to save the selected post when somebody saves the widget. To do so, just one more line is required right before `$instance` is returned.

```
$instance['post'] = $new_instance['post'];
```

This adds the new post to the instance array that will be used to update the instance.

#### This should be enough..

..to help you on your way. Good luck with displaying the post in the widget!

Comment: Yeah sorry for the code formatting, i haven't use PHP since a long time and never Wordpress, i'm a little bit confuse with the syntax and all the sample code i find. Thanks for your answer, that was the one i got in mind but i was hoping for something shorter from wordpress ^^ If there isn't i will implement it this way, thanks again for the sample code and the explanation. That was all i needed to end that website.

Comment: Well, you could use [`wp_dropdown_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) for the dropdown itself, but I'd advise against it as it presets several arguments and is therefore, in my opinion, less transparent. Either way, if the answer answers your question, please accept it as the answer so that it won't show up as unanswered anymore :-).